# How do I rewrite this to use the compass functions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, compass-sass

Can anyone help me rewrite this using the compass functions?

```
-webkit-transition: opacity .15s ease, -webkit-transform .15s ease
-moz-transition: opacity .15s ease, -moz-transform .15s ease
-o-transition: opacity .15s ease, -o-transform .15s ease
```

I don't know how to handle the -*-transform argument. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't currently any helper in Compass for that, but you could file an issue on github and we'll look into it. In the meantime, many cases can be solved by the use of 'all':

```
@include transition(all .15s ease);
```